# Как интегрировать статистику аккаунта Stack Overflow в свой сайт?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, api

[У меня есть среда для разработки сайтов.](https://universitykids.ru/)

Как грамотно интегрировать Stack Overflow в свой сайт? Есть ли какие нибудь модули для этого, написанные на JavaScript?

Дополнения:

Что бы хотелось:

1. Регистрацию через аккаунт Stack Overflow.
2. Получить статистику аккаунта Stack Overflow: репутация, знаки 
   и т.д.

Мне бы хотелось интегрировать это на сайт, для того, что бы можно было использовать эту информацию как дополнение к основному аккаунту клиента, если он этого пожелает.
Есть проект на React devconnector который я хочу интегрировать с web components. Что бы информацию разработчику не пришлось вводить заного, она бралась бы с этого сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы дополнили, чего именно хотите, а то не совсем ясно =/

Comment: Написал дополнения. Мне статистика с сайта нужна в основном. Она открывает достаточно широкий спектр возможностей для проекта.

Comment: @Sergey спросите у @ Grundy http://grundyjs.online

Comment: Спрошу, Я только сейчас вариант для production доделаю. Здесь всё медленно работает. И я новости через rss сделал. Ленту вопроса можно будет тоже интегрировать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Как грамотно интегрировать в свой сайт, сайт stackoverflow ?

У Stack Exchange есть API, к которому предоставляется достаточно подробная информация на https://api.stackexchange.com/

> Есть ли какие нибудь модули для этого написанные на JavaScript ?

Для примера есть минимальный [js-lib](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib). Т.к. API достаточно прост в работе, скорее всего, дополнительных модулей Вам не понадобится.

> Регистрацию через аккаунт stackoverflow.

Как авторизовать пользователя см. на странице [Authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). Минимальный пример авторизации есть на странице [js-lib](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib).

> Получить статистику к аккаунту с сайта stackoverflow: репутация, знаки и т.д.

Посмотрите [список доступных методов](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Репутацию можно получить через [`users/me`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me), знаки через [`users/me/badges`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-badges)

Comment: js-lib не работает у меня. Регистрация зависает с ошибой 

Application Login Failure
An error occurred while login into an application.

Error Details
error description: unexpected domain on proxy url

Comment: @Sergey Откровенно говоря, сейчас нет времени разбираться, протестировал пример в доках и он работает. Попробуйте составить минимальный пример из Вашего приложения и задать вопрос на основном сайте или в чате.